# ElasticSearch returns "index not found error" for an index that exists

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have an index pattern "barney", which shows on Kibana Management screen and on Discover. But when I hit the **_cat/indices** API, it does not show the index pattern in the list of indices returned.

When triggering **barney/_search**, it returns this error

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "index_not_found_exception",
            "reason": "no such index",
            "resource.type": "index_or_alias",
            "resource.id": "<redacted-uuid>",
            "index_uuid": "_na_",
            "index": "<redacted-uuid>"
        }
    ],
    "type": "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason": "no such index",
    "resource.type": "index_or_alias",
    "resource.id": "<redacted-uuid>",
    "index_uuid": "_na_",
    "index": "<redacted-uuid>"
},
"status": 404
```

If the index exists on Management in Kibana, why does it return an error with the API requests?
The Kibana version being used is 6.4.3.

Comment: It is possible index/alias might got deleted ? Index pattern might have been created when it exists but later it might have been deleted. Even if index is deleted it will still show up in kibana index patterns

Comment: Index pattern is not equal to Index. The index pattern is just a template for your index. You will get an index not found error even if you have a pattern but not an index.